# How to implement MySQL Start Transaction and Rollback

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to implement 'start transaction and rollback' on 2 queries that update a table in a stored procedure. I want the second query to only execute if the first query was successful. I really don't know how to do this. I can't seem to understand MySQL documentation. Here are my queries:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE user_id = 1

    UPDATE table SET status = 2 WHERE user_id = 2 

END;
```

Comment: I'm marking this duplicate, because I really think that doing this from a stored proc is how you would probably end up implementing your logic.

Comment: One form of 'failure' is if an update does not find a row to update. This will not throw a system error or cause a handler to be invoked. You can check this by testing row_count(); immediately after the update statement. This has limited use since it supposes you know how many rows should be updated - but if only one then it may be useful.